# slow download speed while transmitting image from windows to wsl by ros2 humble and ros2-for-unity

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, ros2

I am currently working on a project where I am using ROS2-for-Unity(standalone version) to create a node that publishes a topic transmitting image data. However, I am encountering an issue with the transmission speed of the images when subscribing to this topic on the WSL side. The image transmission speed is significantly slower than expected.

To diagnose the issue, I used btop  to monitor the network I/O and found that the download speed on the WSL side (80Mbps) is much lower than the upload speed on the Windows side (560Mbps).

Here are the details of my setup:

Operating System: Windows 11

WSL2 Version: Ubuntu 22.04

ROS Version: ROS Humble

CPU: Intel i7-12650H

Any help would be greatly appreciated！